# Does Math.SE accept non-research-level Theoretical Computer Science questions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

According to the CSTheory.SE FAQ, it does, but there isn't anything in the Math.SE FAQ that specifically allows these questions.

Could the Math.SE FAQ be amended to correspond to the CSTheory.SE FAQ's assertion that such questions are on-topic?

Example: [*Subset sum, Pseudo-polynomial time dynamic programming solution?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481157)

Comment: I don't think there is any problem with CS questions, but we generally do not like «tell me about X» questions. In particular, they are not questions.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Thanks. I Googled the question, found a couple of good examples for the OP, and closed the question as "Off-Topic."  In the meantime, could the Math.SE FAQ be clarified to more closely align with the CSTheory.SE FAQ?

Comment: To more closed align with the CSTheory.SE FAQ in what aspect, specifically?

Comment: The CSTheory.SE FAQ states that non-research-level Theoretical Computer Science questions should be directed at Math.SE. The Math.SE FAQ does not specifically address those kinds of questions.

Comment: ...is that edit really necessary? I'd think "for all levels" was clear enough. And since people here have said $\text{Computer Science}\subseteq\text{Mathematics}$...

Comment: @J.M.: $\subseteq$ or $\subset$?

Comment: Mind you, this sentence in CSTheory.SE FAQ irritates me a bit, because basically it means that they treat Math.SE as a generic dump site. For example the coding theory questions that have been discussed in CSTheory.SE are IMVHO hardly at the research level. An advanced undergraduate/practicing engineer seems to be closer to the mark. Granted, coding theory is not really a mainstream CSTheory topic. Just saying. I think that the kind of question asked in the link would be off-topic here, and we should not welcome that kind of material here.

Comment: @cardinal: $\subset$ is ambiguous. Do you mean $\subseteq$ or $\subsetneq$?

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1966/migration-from-cstheory-to-math-se

Comment: @Asaf, Consider the question (Q) asking whether a given symbol must be understood as $\subseteq$ or as $\subset$. I find unlikely that somebody asking (Q) would use $\subset$ for $\subseteq$. Only somebody using $\subset$ for $\subsetneq$ could ask (Q), don't you think?

Comment: It's awesome that we're discussing ambiguous alphabets depending on context in a computer science meta-thread.

Comment: @UnreasonableSin: You're welcome.

Comment: @Didier: I'm not what you're trying to say here; I don't use $\subset$ *at all*, and I often pick on others who do. Mostly because this symbol is ambiguous. Also, I guess nonsensical sarcasm doesn't go across comments very well :-)

Comment: @Asaf, I am *trying* nothing here and you see sarcasm where there is mainly puzzlement. Why do you *pick on* people who use $\subset$? Why did you see fit to *pick on* cardinal's comment? Since said comment was as unambiguous as can be, was it *sarcasm* from your part? (Just repeating the question of my first comment (which you did not answer), using another formulation.)

Comment: @Didier: The nonsensical sarcasm was on my side. I pick on the use of $\subset$ because there are two factions for "proper" and "improper" inclusion with this symbol, while $\subseteq$ and $\subsetneq$ have only one meaning. To see this point recall that this question came up more than once on the main site (either as a question or in the comments to answers and so). When J.M. wrote his comment, he used the unambiguous notation $\subseteq$ to say that it is a subset, but surely everyone knows it is a *proper* subset. Using $\subset$ to ask that was a confusing action (not to me, of course...)

Comment: Wow. A very dry attempt at levity fell very, very flat. (@AsafKaragila: Did you really interpret my tongue-in-cheek remark to J.M. as a *serious* question?)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Completely beside the point (as I did not intend to derail the discussion), but I find your comments on notation a tad peculiar.

Comment: @Asaf: *Now* you answered my question, thanks. I do not share your premises on these notational matters. Case closed.

Comment: So then, is the answer to my question, *"Obvious question is obvious.  Here, have some set theory"?*

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, you screwed up. I got notified because of the `@NUE`

Comment: @Jyrki, we seldom migrate a question from cstheory to math.se. And when I do so I also edit the question after the migration to make it clear and suitable. I often answer the question myself after the migration. Let me know if you think a specific migration has been bad. What we usually do is commenting that the question might be suitable for math.se. We don't dump questions on math.se.